# UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() always returns UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone on iPad 4.3 Simulator?

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocos2d-iphone

I am new to iOS development and following along with the book "Learning Cocos2d, A Hands-on Guide to Building iOS Games with Cocos2d, Box2d, and Chipmunk".

I have noticed that the UI buttons and viking characher I have rendered in chapter 2 do not match the book... the apparent cause is that the book instructs you to use the UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() macro to determine whether you are running an iPad or an iPhone, but it appears that no matter whether I set the scheme in xcode to use iPad 4.3 or iPhone 4.3, the macro always reports that I am running on the phone, not the pad.

Is there some sort of problem with the macro?  Is this because I am running only on the simulator?  I do not have an actual device on which to test any of this.  What am I to do when this macro fails like this?

Comment: Please show us your code. Have you actually configured your app to be Universal?

Comment: @OleBegemann Thanks for this comment!  It wasn't my code at all, but rather that yes, there is a xCode setting for "Universal" that I simply hadn't toggled.  If you make an answer for this comment I'll select it as the correct answer to the question.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You need to make sure that your project is configured to build a "Universal" app. An iPhone app running on the iPad will still identify its UI idiom as "iPhone".